# INSERT INTO without field names

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010, field

I am trying to use the INSERT INTO Statement without defining my column field names. I know this is possible but i am jus not able to do it. The SQL string i currently have is,

```
  strSQL = " INSERT INTO MLE_Table (pnr, [Overall Assesment], risk, reason, justification)" & _
           " SELECT tbl_Import.pnr, tbl_Import.[Overall Assesment], tbl_Import.risk, tbl_Import.reason, tbl_Import.justification " & _
           " FROM tbl_Import;"
```

now, in this code i have used my field names. but I dont want to do that.
I want the SQL to insert fields into the new table only when the field names of both tables match.

I think it can be done by a For Each Loop, but I am not sure.

Is there anyone who has done this before.. I am using MS Access 2010.

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: If you don't use names, the only thing that'll happen is it will do things positionally (first column in select goes into first column in table). This is far *more* brittle. In SQL, you should, wherever possible, reference columns by *name* rather than by *position*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use DAO:

```
Public Sub CopyRecords()

  Dim rstSource   As DAO.Recordset
  Dim rstInsert   As DAO.Recordset
  Dim fld         As DAO.Field
  Dim strSQL      As String
  Dim lngLoop     As Long
  Dim lngCount    As Long

  strSQL = "SELECT Top 1 * FROM tblInsert"    
  Set rstInsert = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
  strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tblSource"    
  Set rstSource = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)

  With rstSource
    lngCount = .RecordCount
    For lngLoop = 1 To lngCount
      With rstInsert
        .AddNew
          For Each fld In rstSource.Fields
            With fld
              If .Attributes And dbAutoIncrField Then
                ' Skip Autonumber or GUID field.
              ElseIf .Name = "Something" Then
                ' Insert default value.
                rstInsert.Fields(.Name).Value = 0
              ElseIf .Name = "SomethingElse Then
                ' Ignore this field.
              Else
                ' Copy field content.
                rstInsert.Fields(.Name).Value = .Value
              End If
            End With
          Next
        .Update
      End With
      .MoveNext
    Next
    rstInsert.Close
    .Close
  End With

  Set rstInsert = Nothing
  Set rstSource = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: great code!! the logic is something i was looking for..I tried to execute it. I got an error. I think some modifications Need to be made. the error was on the line: ` rstInsert.Fields(.Name).Value = .Value`   and the error was: ** Item not found in this collection**

Comment: Yeps, the assumption is identical table schemas. If not, you can add, exchange, or exclude field names.

Comment: ofcourse i changed the (.Name) = " pnr ". pnr is the Name of the first column of my source table.

Comment: rstInsert.Fields(.Name).Value = .Value    this line is a bit confusing. can you please explain what is (.value )? is it the value of the corresponding field in the source table??

Comment: Property _Value_ is exactly that: The value of the field. It is the default property of the field, so in many cases it can be left out. However, in _VB.NET_ and _C#_ there is no default property, so even in the cases in _VBA_ where it is not mandatory, many (including me) specify it anyway. It turns into a habit and will never cause any error.

Comment: But Gustav you have not specified that it is the value of the source field. How will the code know from where to take the value? I think it is because of this I am getting an error.   rstInsert.Fields(.Name).Value = .Value (insert table value is equal to what value????)

Comment: Ok, i guess I understand the answer to my previous question. Since it is in a for Loop of every field in the source table the (.value) field would automatically refer to value of that particular field.... Then still the question, why am i getting this error?

Comment: the (.Name) code line, it is the Name of a field in the target table correct??

Comment: Yes. It belongs to `For Each fld In rstSource.Fields`

Comment: ok, now i played around with the code. i found out that within your WITH Loop, the ELSE IF part works but the ELSE part does not work....  the ELSE IF part also does not work perfectly as it just adds an empty record into the target table everytime I run the code. any ideas??

Comment: The original code works _as is_ for two tables with similar schemas and an autonumber Id. The only things to do is to exclude fields that don't exist in the insert table, and to include default or calculated values for fields in the insert table that must have values not found in the source table, and to map identical fields that have different names in the two tables.